# Examples for Analytic contraction Semigroups on Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for sources of examples of analytic semigroups of contractions on spaces like the $L_{p}$ and Sobolev spaces and similar. I already looked through some sources and they tend to only prove results for very specific operators like the laplacian or only feature results for $L_{p}$ but not the sobolev spaces.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this by any stretch but Lunardi's book "Analytic Semigroups and Optimal Regularity in Parabolic Problems" gives at least a wide variety of examples (chapter 3) for elliptic differential operators. But from what I know, it is unusual to generate semigroups in sobolev spaces if you can do it in $L^p$.